# Testing ASP.NET Core Docker Container with Travis CI

Tags: bash, docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile, .net-core

So I've configured my `.travis.yml` to build and test my ASP.NET Core project, but now I've to configure it to run in docker. So far so good, I've the Dockerfile for the build, but then I started to figure:

- Should I run the testing inside the Docker Container or outside? Or Does it even matter?
- If I should do it inside how could this be achieved? since `dotnet test` doesn't have `**/*/` support and my container doesn't run my bash script.

## UPDATE:

- Or should I build and test outside and later create the dockerimage?

The Dockerfile is:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest
ARG source=.
WORKDIR /usr/src/project

COPY $source .

RUN dotnet restore

EXPOSE 5000
CMD dotnet build **/*/project.json
```

And the `.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd test/
for D in `find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type d`
do
        if [ -a ./project.json ]
        then
            ( cd ${D}; dotnet test;)
        fi
done
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would you mind sharing what did you end up doing ?

Comment: @valorl Sorry I forgot, my solution is in the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I decided that the docker build and publish should only be done if the build and test succeeded

**.travis.yml**

```
language: csharp

sudo: required


solution: Solution.sln


mono: none

dotnet: 1.0.0-preview2-1-003177


services:

    - docker


install:

    - npm install -g bower

    - npm install -g gulp


before_script:

    - chmod a+x ./scripts/test.sh


script:

    - dotnet restore && dotnet build **/*/project.json

    - ./scripts/test.sh --quite verify

    - if [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" == "master" ] ; then 

      dotnet publish --no-build src/Main -o publish/ ;

      docker build -t project . ;

      fi

    

after_success: 

    - if [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" == "master" ] ; then 

      /* Push to docker repo */

      fi
```